# Создание представления для выдачи товарооборота по месяцам? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Коллеги, не могу составить сложный, но очень пракичный запрос.

Есть у меня товар (название, единица измерения)
поставщик (название)
журнал покупок (ид, ид_товара, ид_поставщика, цена, количество (предполагается та же единица измерения, что и товар), дата_покупки (DATE))
журнал продаж (ид, ид_товара, ид_поставщика, цена, количество (предполагается та же единица измерения, что и товар), дата_продажи(DATE))

Мне нужно создать представление (виртуальную таблицу), которая бы мне выводила товарооборот по месяцам (под товароборотом понимается сумма денег (количество * цена), которая была получена в результате продаж за месяц)).

Очень жду вашей помощи!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос `create table` для журнала продаж и даты продаж. А также `insert into`

Comment: Создайте online fiddle со структурами таблиц и тестовыми данными. Покажите требуемый ответ для именно таких данных. Также укажите точную версию MySQL.

Comment: сведется все к тому, что будет группировка по `year(d), month(d)`

Answer (score -1):

Примерно так:

```
SELECT SUM(<цена>*<количество>) as summ FROM <журнал_продаж>
GROUP BY MOUNTH(<дата>);
```